# Databricks Autoloader read json with different schema

Tags: databricks, autoload

I am have different schema of json  files to be read and writing to databricks delta table.

the schema maybe

{"Col1": "testing" ,"Col2" :{ "subcol1":"testing2"}}

or

{"col1": "testing2", "Col2": [{ "subcol1":"testing2"}, { "subcol1":"testing3"}]

what should be the schema input to the sparkreadstream such that I can have

col1       col2_subcol1
testing1    testing2
testing2    testing2
testing2     testing3

thanks

Comment: hi.,anyone has the idea ?

Comment: Hi anyone has any idea how to do it ?

Comment: hi anyone has experience and idea ?

Comment: anyone has the idea ?

Comment: I have the same issue, any way to get around!?!